# How to generate RESTful client in JAVA for REST defined in WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, rest, wsdl

I know that WSDL is for defining SOAP based web services but in most of the WSDLs I saw on net, in the WSDL is defined also RESTful "web service"-http:binding.

To generate client for the SOAP I used wsimport tool from JAX-WS (it also generates client classes for the REST but it doesnt work).

So the question is, how to generate REST client based on the WSDL?

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of anyone using WSDL for generating REST clients.  WADL yes, but not WSDL.

Anyway, generating clients for REST services does not make sense.  If you think you want to do that then you are missing the benefits of REST and trying to follow the REST constraints is going to make you do extra work for nothing.

Comment: I had also read on net that WSDL isn't supposed to be for defining REST. But in many(really many) I found REST described. For example:

http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx?WSDL
http://www.webservicex.net/ValidateEmail.asmx?WSDL
http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL
http://www.webservicex.net/WeatherForecast.asmx?wsdl

Comment: That's interesting to know.  I had heard that recent versions of WSDL could describe HTTP apis but I had never seen it used.  I still personally think that metadata documents like this are completely unnecessary and potentially harmful for REST systems.

Comment: A big +1 to Darrel's answer. If clients depend on service descriptions obtained at design time your system is anything but RESTful.

Comment: I cannot agree here, the often missing formal description of REST services are a weakness once it comes to advanced tooling that would otherwise be able to save STT(tm) (stupid typing work) by generating client classes automatically. It takes < 1 minute to generate solid client classes from a WSDL (I do like REST, but that part's still not yet optimal).

Comment: @Bachi You may not agree but the creator of the REST architectural style disagrees with you.  By creating client classes that causes types to be shared between client and server you are defeating one of the primary objectives of REST, i.e. independent evolution of components.  So you are not saving any typing because you don't need those client classes.

Comment: @Darrel Which is only the case in heterogenous setups, whereas SOAP does clearly have its advantages in more homogenous situations. Besides, say you have an interface that delivers 5 text fields - you do need at least some of them and if you code well, you create a client class of sorts holding these. So in either case, you obviously will have some sort of a client class/code, otherwise the whole service would be obsolete. There's no reason why not to get help by having that code generated in a standardized way.

Comment: @Bachi  I didn't say you couldn't or shouldn't use client classes, I'm just saying that's not the way REST works.  Using REST you can enable users to perform domain specific actions without having domain specific code in the client.  Look at how the web browser works for an example.

Comment: I definetly agree..  Let the clients evolve separately - the need to support multiple languages is more moving parts, making REST just an extra node in the middle with no real purpose.

Comment: Agree with @Bachi . Now (2015) professional Java & .NET framework can define multiprotocol service (server side) from one definition, besides SOAP & automatic WSDL - not conflicting with REST (in both serialization JSON/XML). Why can't generate REST client if REST/JSON functionality is equal to SOAP? (For example, network contract is to REST protocol) in 30 sec? Question isn't stupid, but I haven't positive answers, I'm investigating too. Question seems specially important in type safe languages

Comment: @DarrelMiller Seems to me, REST have to important role in networking, Is fashionable, simple. But too often is selected as protocol when should be selected heavier tool

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can auto-generate a SOAP like stub for JAX-RS but it uses WADL which I believe is a WSDL variant.

[Apache CXF does this](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html) and if that doesn't work for you it will also automatically create SOAP endpoints and SOAP clients.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RestDescribe](http://tomayac.de/rest-describe/latest/RestDescribe.html) to generate and compile WSDL, you can generate clients in php, ruby, python, java and C# using this. It generates clean code and there is a good change that you have to tweak it a bit after code generation, you can find good documentation and underlying thoughts behind the tool [here](https://docs.google.com/document/edit?id=1uydmzsDFIiw8OsoMdk5v_s1VW7wrujUmGdUU2zge0fs).

There are few interesting and useful [WADL tools](http://wintermuteblog.blogspot.com/2010/01/wadl-toolbox.html) mentioned on wintermute.

Answer (score 0):

[**IBM Developer network: WSDL2 can describe REST services.**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-restwsdl)

I think in programmers mainstream is holy war SOAP (classic) - REST services. Nobody want this war, these conceptions can coexist - i see this is opinion not only from my and few people, but has grooving support in standards.