# Generate REST from WSDL

Tags: rest, wsdl

I'm looking for best way to automate generation of REST ws. 
We have collection of web services (SOAP) with WSDLs generated for them. I was required to provide different APIs to invoke these web services. (PHP, Pyton, REST, CLI ...)
One of requirement is to have REST API for these ws.

What is the best way to generate REST client/server, is there any automatic tools for that?
There is a chance that WSDLs will change each release.

Thanks

Comment: REST and WSDL are fundamentally opposite and incompatible concepts.... WSDL/SOAP services are built around **functions** and methods (*do something with customer*), while REST is based on **resources** (HTTP `GET /customer/5`). I **highly** doubt you'll be able to get any meaningful "transformation" of a SOAP WSDL into anything that even remotely resembles a REST service....

Comment: @marc_s Theory from protocol designers is one. Real life is the second, when REST is selected for architecture, because is the only protocol projector understand, is fashionable, every young webmaster understand etc ... and should be used something from *classic web-services*. I think question is good (but I cant find tool). 2nd part on my opinion is below answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32744753/794606

Answer (score 3):

**It's not possible to generate REST API from WSDL.** You can't  mix oranges and apples

SOAP is a protocol build on top of HTTP. A WebService is represented by a set of methods/actions. You can see a WebService as sophisticated RPC. Generally we can say that **WebServices are about verbs**, to call remote methods/actions. A WebService also doesn't have uniform interface and that's the reason why WSDL exists.

REST is architectural style (scope is broader than just API). REST API is represented by a set of resources and representations. A resource is source of an information and is managed via uniform interface. Generally we can say that **REST API is about nouns**. Because all resources must have uniform interface there is no need for WADL (an unsuccessful attempt to create something like WSDL for REST).

I doubt you can automatically transform verbs into nouns, etc.

Comment: I understand You (TOTALLY ;) ), but not agree. Modern server framework for main languages (Java C#) can produce full service for free (few annotations / attributes) with SOAP+WSDL, REST (over JSOM/XML up to user). If integrators have (for free) WSDL, why don't generate type-safe client code (classes) in 30sec? Why must manually make error-prone repeatable code? 1st part of my opinion under question.

Comment: @JacekCz you will lost *loose coupling* because of the stub generation. If a service description changes then you have to re-generate the code, and recompile, re-deploy, your application. Simply, this kind of description prevents run-time adaptation of an API change. That's why ;)

Comment: 1. Hardened API isn't university theory, its real life in business. 2. real fife story from one your friend: grooving set of "endpoints" (URI'u) with consistent (even transactional) data. *verbs* become methods etc etc. Change of protocol at this stage? No! No! No! Build over protocol classic webservice. Change of data over URL isn't API change? This is api change. Compiled (say safe) way versus intepreted (not need to recompile, but can shot in foot).

Comment: 3 I'm not fanatic of SOAP, primary 2-language version of solution goes to Apache Thrift "IDL first" solution, very elegant and performant service (BTW has conception of dynamic upgrade fields in protocol version, You will like it). Only integrated ancient 3rd Delphi was incapable "speak in thrift" so move to "coomon denominator" generated SOAP. Keeping in hands 3 languages/environment/software provider solution never want fluent api

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below article that describes how to use WSDL2.0 to describe REST Services. It can only be used if the intended message format is XML.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-restwsdl/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rewriting an existing SOAP-based web service, use API Express to present it as a mobile-ready REST service. No conversion necessary. Continue to run the SOAP service and, with a WSDL file and a few configuration parameters, it can easily be integrated into mobile apps as a REST service.

How to Expose a WSDL Service (SOAP) as REST API: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-expose-a-wsdl-service-soap-as-rest-api

Appery.io API Express: https://appery.io/api-express/