# ReST webservice client - generate from WSDL or not?

Tags: java, rest

I've some confusions about ReST clients and need a bit of help.

For ReST, does the service provider give WSDL document or not? If not, how does the client will know what kind of JSON data to expect? When I invoke the rest client, I will recieve the JSON/XML response in a string format which I'll need to convert it into a Java object(or Javascript, if using on client side) to do any meaningful tasks with the response. So it seems like I, as a client developer, need to know the WSDL or the Schema definition so that I can build a java object similar to the JSON response I'm expecting. But if you go by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689122/how-to-generate-restful-client-in-java-for-rest-defined-in-wsdl), generating a client class based on the service definition flies directly in the face of ReST fullness. If that is the case, how do I go about creating my client code?

Answer (score 0):

[WADL/Web Application Description Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language) is not a standard but is gaining popularity for REST APIs contract definition.

> The Web Application Description Language (WADL) is a machine-readable
>   XML description of HTTP-based web applications (typically REST web
>   services).[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language) WADL models the resources provided by a service and the
>   relationships between them.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language) WADL is intended to simplify the reuse
>   of web services that are based on the existing HTTP architecture of
>   the Web.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language)[2] It is platform and language independent and aims to
>   promote reuse of applications beyond the basic use in a web
>   browser.

Answer (score 0):

For documentation:

https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/master/modules/swagger-jaxrs

For client code:

https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui

- You integrate the library and annotate your resources and online documentation is generated on the fly.
- You also need a client for which you can integrate the ui.

The dynamically generated REST client looks something like this:

http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/